# How can I recursively update a command in a 'for' loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros, pgffor

I am trying to plot sums of functions, with parameters specified by the user, using `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\myfun}[2]{(cos(#1*\x) + sin(#2*\x))}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:100]
            \addplot[red,samples=300]{\myfun{10}{20}+\myfun{5}{10}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That works, but I want the user to input a command of the form `\plotwave{{10,20},{5,10}}` (so I can use the same parameters to plot multiple parametric functions, `\myfuna`, `\myfunb`, etc.). So, I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfplots}

\newcommand{\myfun}[2]{(cos(#1*\x) + sin(#2*\x))}
\newcommand{\plotwave}[1]{
    \newcounter{ind}
    \newcommand{\aaa}{0}
    \newcommand{\bbb}{0}
    \newcommand{\plotcommand}{0}
    \newcommand{\oldplotcommand}{0}
    \foreach \z in {#1} {
        \setcounter{ind}{0}
        \foreach \y in \z {
            \stepcounter{ind}
            \ifnum\the\value{ind}=1
                \global\let\aaa\y
            \else
                \global\let\bbb\y
            \fi
        }
        \let\oldplotcommand\plotcommand
        \gdef\plotcommand{\oldplotcommand + \myfun{\aaa}{\bbb}}
    }
    \addplot[red,samples=300]{\plotcommand};
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:100]
            \plotwave{{100,200},{10,20}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But that does not work. No errors, but only the second function is plotted instead of sum of the two functions. Adding `\global` to the `\let` command crashes with `TeX capacity exceeded`. The `\gdef\plotcommand{\oldplotcommand + \myfun{\aaa}{\bbb}}` part does not seem to do what I was expecting it to do. Is there a way to achieve what I want using `pgffor` and `pgfplots`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the one hand each iteration of `\foreach` is carried out in its own local scope/group, therefore things cannot work out if `\let` is not preceded by `\global`.

On the other hand if `\let` is preceded by `\global`, then `\oldplotcommand` globally is assigned the meaning which `\plotcommand` has at the time of performing the `\let`-assignment.

`\plotcommand` in turn is defined to call `\oldplotcommand`.

Thus you end up with a command `\oldplotcommand` which recursively, but not tail-recursively(!), calls itself again and again whereby more and more sequences `+ \myfun{\aaa}{\bbb}` in the token-stream are accumulated behind the call to `\oldplotommand` until a `! TeX capacity exceeded`-error occurs.

If you add `\show`-commands

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfplots}

\newcommand{\myfun}[2]{(cos(#1*\x) + sin(#2*\x))}
\newcommand{\plotwave}[1]{
    \newcounter{ind}
    \newcommand{\aaa}{0}
    \newcommand{\bbb}{0}
    \newcommand{\plotcommand}{0}
    \newcommand{\oldplotcommand}{0}
    \foreach \z in {#1} {
        \setcounter{ind}{0}
        \foreach \y in \z {
            \stepcounter{ind}
            \ifnum\the\value{ind}=1
                \global\let\aaa\y
            \else
                \global\let\bbb\y
            \fi
        }
        \global\let\oldplotcommand\plotcommand
        \gdef\plotcommand{\oldplotcommand + \myfun{\aaa}{\bbb}}
    }
    \show\plotcommand
    \show\oldplotcommand
    \addplot[red,samples=300]{\plotcommand};
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:100]
            \plotwave{{100,200},{10,20}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

, then messages on the console reveal:

```
> \plotcommand=macro:
->\oldplotcommand + \myfun {\aaa }{\bbb }.
\plotwave ...{\aaa }{\bbb }} } \show \plotcommand 
                                                  \show \oldplotcommand \add...
l.31             \plotwave{{100,200},{10,20}}
                                             ;
? 
> \oldplotcommand=macro:
->\oldplotcommand + \myfun {\aaa }{\bbb }.
\plotwave ...w \plotcommand \show \oldplotcommand
```

As you can see: `\oldplotcommand` is defined to prepend both a call to itself and the token-sequence `+ \myfun{\aaa}{\bbb}` to the token-stream. Thus with each `\oldplotcommand`-iteration another sequence `+ \myfun{\aaa}{\bbb}` is accumulated behind the call to `\oldplotcommand` coming from that iteration.
As soon as there isn't enough memory any more for accumulating another sequence `+ \myfun{\aaa}{\bbb}` behind the call to `\oldplotcommand` you get the `! TeX capacity exceeded`-error.

In order to prevent this self-calling recursion, within the definition-text of `\plotcommand`, which with your code is defined as

```
\gdef\plotcommand{\oldplotcommand + \myfun{\aaa}{\bbb}}
```

, the tokens `\oldplotcommand` and `\aaa` and `\bbb` need to be expanded.

You could do this with an immense `\expandafter`-orgy, i.e., three `\expandafter`-chains, one `\expandafter`-chain for one of the tokens that shall be expanded:

```
% Chain 1   |Chain 2    |Chain 3
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter            \expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter                        \gdef
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter            \expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter                        \plotcommand
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter            \expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter                        {%
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter            \oldplotcommand
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter            +%
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter            \myfun
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter            {%
\expandafter\aaa
\expandafter}%
\expandafter{%
\bbb}}
```

If `\unexpanded` from the e-TeX-extensions is available, you can do:

```
\xdef\plotcommand{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter{\oldplotcommand + \myfun}% 
  {\unexpanded\expandafter{\aaa}}% 
  {\unexpanded\expandafter{\bbb}}%
}%
```

Actually you don't need `\oldplotcommand`, you can have `\plotcommand` expanded instead:

```
\xdef\plotcommand{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter{\plotcommand + \myfun}% 
  {\unexpanded\expandafter{\aaa}}% 
  {\unexpanded\expandafter{\bbb}}%
}%
```

With this slight modification your code works out:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfplots}

% allocate scratch-count-register and define scratch-macros only once instead
% of doing this whenever carrying out `\plotwave` and thus repeatedly:
\newcounter{ind}
\newcommand{\aaa}{0}
\newcommand{\bbb}{0}
\newcommand{\plotcommand}{0}

\newcommand{\myfun}[2]{(cos(#1*\x) + sin(#2*\x))}

\newcommand{\plotwave}[1]{%%
    \renewcommand{\plotcommand}{0}%%
    \renewcommand{\aaa}{0}%%
    \renewcommand{\bbb}{0}%%
    \foreach \z in {#1} {%%
        \setcounter{ind}{0}%%
        \foreach \y in \z {%%
            \stepcounter{ind}%%
            \ifnum\the\value{ind}=1 %%
                \global\let\aaa\y
            \else
                \global\let\bbb\y
            \fi
        }%%
        \xdef\plotcommand{%%
          \unexpanded\expandafter{\plotcommand + \myfun}%%
          {\unexpanded\expandafter{\aaa}}%%
          {\unexpanded\expandafter{\bbb}}%%
        }%%
    }%%
    %\show\plotcommand
    \addplot[red,samples=300]{\plotcommand};%%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:100]
            \plotwave{{100,200},{10,20}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

If you don't want to use additional packages you can, e.g., collect things within a single scratch-macro instead of using four scratch-macros `\aaa`, `\bbb`, `\plotcommand` and `\oldplotcommand`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfplots}

\newcommand\scratchmacro{}%

\newcommand{\myfun}[2]{(cos(#1*\x) + sin(#2*\x))}%

\newcommand{\plotwave}[3]{%%%
    \gdef\scratchmacro{}%
    \foreach \z in {#3}{%
        \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\scratchmacro}$%<-check if \scratchmacro is defined empty/first \foreach iteration
          \xdef\scratchmacro{\unexpanded\expandafter{\scratchmacro#2}}%
        \else
          \xdef\scratchmacro{\unexpanded\expandafter{\scratchmacro#1#2}}%
        \fi
        \foreach \y in \z {%
            \xdef\scratchmacro{\unexpanded\expandafter{\scratchmacro}{\y}}%
            %If you want only toplevel-expansion of \y instead of full expansion of \y :
            %\xdef\scratchmacro{\unexpanded\expandafter{\scratchmacro}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\y}}}%
        }%
    }%
    %\show\scratchmacro
    \addplot[red,samples=300]{\scratchmacro};
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:100]
            \plotwave{+}{\myfun}{{100,200},{10,20}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you can use a scratch-token-register.
Unlike with the example above with the example below  `\y` will be top-level-expanded only instead of being expanded fully:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfplots}

\newtoks\scratchtoks{}%

\newcommand{\myfun}[2]{(cos(#1*\x) + sin(#2*\x))}%

\newcommand{\plotwave}[3]{%%%
    \global\scratchtoks{}%
    \foreach \z in {#3}{%
        \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\the\scratchtoks}$%<-check if \scratchtoks is empty/first \foreach iteration
          \global\scratchtoks\expandafter{\the\scratchtoks#2}%
        \else
          \global\scratchtoks\expandafter{\the\scratchtoks#1#2}%
        \fi
        \foreach \y in \z {%
           \global\scratchtoks\expandafter{\the\expandafter\scratchtoks\expandafter{\y}}%
        }%
    }%
    %\showthe\scratchtoks
    \addplot[red,samples=300]{\the\scratchtoks};
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:100]
            \plotwave{+}{\myfun}{{100,200},{10,20}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accepted this over the other two excellent answers because it explains why my code was not working. Thank you!

Comment: After a mile of excellent explanation and work can not miss my positive vote.

Answer (score 9):

It's possible with `expl3`: from the command

```
\plotwave[red,samples=300]{\myfun}{{0,5},{10,20}}
```

we build

```
\addplot[red,samples=300]{\myfun{0}{5}+\myfun{10}{20}}
```

and execute it.

The first mandatory argument is any predefined function with a certain number of arguments, the second mandatory argument is a comma separated list of comma separated lists with the required number of items each.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\newcommand{\myfun}[2]{(cos(#1*\x) + sin(#2*\x))}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\plotwave}{O{}mm}
 {% #1 = options to \addplot
  % #2 = function to use 
  % #3 = list of parameters 
  \rushi_plotwave:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__rushi_plotwave_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__rushi_plotwave_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \rushi_plotwave:nnn
 {
  % split the list of parameters at commas
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__rushi_plotwave_in_seq { #3 }
  % clear the sequence that will get the various parts to sum
  \seq_clear:N \l__rushi_plotwave_out_seq
  % populate it
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__rushi_plotwave_in_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__rushi_plotwave_out_seq
     {
      % we want to transform {a,b} into {a}{b}
      % so to obtain \myfun{a}{b}; #2 is the function to use
      \exp_not:N #2 \clist_map_function:nN { ##1 } \__rushi_plotwave_arg:n
     }
   }
  % draw the plot
  \addplot[#1]{\seq_use:Nn \l__rushi_plotwave_out_seq { + }}
 }

% helper command to transform {a,b} into {a}{b}
\cs_new:Nn \__rushi_plotwave_arg:n { {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=0:100]
    \plotwave[red,samples=300]{\myfun}{{0,5},{10,20}};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution using `\epxandonce` (from `etoolbox`) and the `.list` handler of `pgfkeys`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\myfun}[2]{(cos(#1*\x) + sin(#2*\x))}
\newcommand{\plotwave}[1]{
  \def\plotcommand{0}
  \pgfset{
    @plotwave/.is family,@plotwave, % my family
    addwave/.code args={##1,##2}{
      \edef\plotcommand{\expandonce\plotcommand + \noexpand\myfun{##1}{##2}}
    },
    addwave/.list={#1},
  }
  \typeout{\meaning\plotcommand} % debug !!!
  \addplot[red,samples=1000]{\plotcommand};
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:100]
            \plotwave{{100,200},{10,20}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, a similar solution also based on `\expandonce` but with `\pgfplotsforeach` this time:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\myfun}[2]{(cos(#1*\x) + sin(#2*\x))}
\newcommand{\plotwave}[1]{
  \def\plotcommand{0}
  \def\addwave##1,##2\endaddwave{
    \edef\plotcommand{\expandonce\plotcommand + \noexpand\myfun{##1}{##2}}
  }
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \couple in {{#1}}{
    \expandafter\addwave\couple\endaddwave
  }
  \typeout{\meaning\plotcommand} % # debug !!!
  \addplot[red,samples=1000]{\plotcommand};
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:100]
            \plotwave{{100,200},{10,20}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```